# R data.table error - typeof x != typeof i

Tags: r, data.table

I am running into an error trying to do a data.table join:

```
setkey(th1, split1, market, dept_size, bool_3)

th1[J(split1_training_value,markets[m], chains[c], dept_sizes[d], bool_3_value)]
Error in `[.data.table`(th1, J(split1_training_value, markets[m], chains[c],  : 
  typeof x.dept_size (double) != typeof i.dept_size (integer)
```

I checked the structure and input, and I do have the same class (numeric), so I don't understand the problem:

```
> class(dept_sizes[d])
[1] "numeric"

> class(th1$dept_size)
[1] "numeric"
```

---

```
> typeof(dept_sizes[d])
[1] "double"
> typeof(th1$dept_size)
[1] "double"
```

Comment: do `typeof` for those two

Comment: @KapelNick I added the typeof.

Comment: yes but as you can see error says `typeof i.dept_size` is `integer` and not `double`. so i guess you are missing something about that.

Comment: Yes I saw that. The question is what am I missing...

Comment: As you dont provide any data i cant give an answer to that.

Comment: anyway try converting those two, before join, to different datatype. like using the `as.` function

Comment: any luck? fill me in if you need any additional suggestions

Comment: I am trying to do a subset of the data.table to have a small reproducible example... but data.table subsetting is also non-trivial to me. Arg.

Comment: your key has 4 elements, while your `J` has 5 - *that's* your problem - `chains[c]` is the offending integer, but the bigger issue is your `J` expression

Comment: @eddi Yes I think that was the problem. Thank you.